# Can I initiate a graphical desktop session remotely via ssh?

Tags: remote-desktop, login, screen-sharing, login-screen

A remote machine running 10.8.4 is powered on but at the Login Window, so no user is actually logged in to a desktop session.  Is there a way to log a user in remotely via ssh to create an actual desktop session?

Comment: What version of OS X is the server, and what is your client?  I recall having similar issues with a Lion server and various Windows VNC clients, but I do not recall having any such issue with the ML Screen Sharing client.

Comment: The server and client are both 10.8.4.  I am able to connect via ssh but screen sharing doesn't seem to start if server is at the login window.

Comment: Are you using the native Screen Sharing app in 10.8?  I keep our headless server logged out when not in use but am still able to connect via Screen Sharing and login at it's login window with no issues.  10.8.4 server and 10.8.4 client.  I wonder, is the server's screen sharing settings configured using "Screen Sharing" or "Remote Management" in it's Sharing preferences?  Our Macs are all set with Remote Management.

Comment: thanks, turns out my machine had a stalled loginwindow process which was preventing screen sharing from starting.  i've updated my question.  would still like to know if it's possible to initiate a desktop session via ssh.

Comment: +1 for whether it is the native SS app or not, but as for @MrRabbit's other question, we use Screen Sharing and *not* Remote Management here and it works out OK.